# How to use curlpp's InfoGetter?

Tags: c++, libcurl, curlpp

I'm using curlpp in an application and need to get the URL I was redirected to. Apparently there are two ways: track the `Location` headers (ugly) or use `curlpp::InfoGetter` (the c++ counterpart of `curl_easy_getinfo()`).

But how do I use `curlpp::InfoGetter`? I cant't find any examples. Does anyone have a short snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just found it out by myself:

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Infos.hpp>

curlpp::Easy request;
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url("http://www.example.com/"));
request.perform();
std::string effective_url = curlpp::infos::EffectiveUrl::get(request);
```

You may use any other subclass of `curl::Info` found in http://bitbucket.org/jpbarrette/curlpp/src/tip/include/curlpp/Infos.hpp instead of `curlpp::infos::EffectiveUrl`.

Comment: get() is a static member function. You can therefore skip the instance of curlpp::infos::EffectiveUrl and just use curlpp::infos::EffectiveUrl::get(request). I'll edit it if you don't mind.